# How do you calculate arrival rates and service rates?

Tags: probability, self-learning, operations-research, queueing-theory

If I have to observe a queue at an electronics shop and I need to perform at least 10 observations, how can I determine what the mean rate of arrival is? or the mean rate of service?

Like lets say that I choose to observe 10 people between 9 AM and 12 PM

```
Person 1 entered at 9:10   -- Left at 9:15
Person 2 entered at 9:15   -- Left at 9:20
Person 3 entered at 9:40   -- Left at 9:50
Person 4 entered at 9:59   -- Left at 10:20
Person 5 entered at 10:30  -- Left at 10:45
Person 6 entered at 10:45  -- Left at 11:00
Person 7 entered at 11:10  -- Left at 11:25
Person 8 entered at 11:20  -- Left at 11:30
Person 9 entered at 11:30  -- Left at 11:45
Person 10 entered at 11:35 -- Left at 11:50
```

How can I determine from those observations what the mean arrival rate is and the mean service rate? Lets say its for hours as well as for every 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean arrival rate can be estimated as total number of arrivals divided by total time spent observing the system, if you assume the arrival rate is constant. If you think the arrival rate varies during the day (for instance, busy at lunch and dinner, slow between meals), then you need to estimate the arrival rate over multiple time intervals (for instance, count arrivals in each 30 minute window and double to get a per-hour rate).

Service rate is trickier. The difference between when a customer enters and when they leave combines waiting time (if there is a line) and service time. One way to estimate mean service rate would be to count the number of customers exiting (after service) per unit time *while there is a continuous line* (always someone waiting). Another way would be to record when each customer starts and ends service, take the difference to get their time in service, and average that. If you assume Markovian service times, the mean service rate is the reciprocal of the mean service time.

Comment: Thank you! So for the example I posted, the mean arrival rate per hour would be 10/3? or 10/1? I'm confused as to whether the amount of hours I spent observing will be the rate for that amount of hours, or if its always just 1 hour.

And the service rate is simply the waiting times of each customers summed up and divided by the number of customers?

Comment: I ask because I'm having issues with a bigger model I made. 60 observations observing a period of 2 hours, so that would be an hourly arrival rate of 30, because 60/2 = 30, right?

But then, I calculated the waiting times of each customer (the difference between the previous customer's exit time and the current customer's arrival time) and got the mean from it, and it's 23.62, but that's already wrong for queing theory because arrival rate must always be smaller than service rate.

Comment: You counted 10 customers arriving in a span of 2 hours 25 minutes, which is about 4.1 customers per hour. Service rate does *not* include waiting time. For a Markovian system, service rate is the reciprocal of the average time a customer spends actually being served. For instance, if the server is a cashier, you measure how long a customer spends from the instant they reach the cashier until the instant they leave, average that and take a reciprocal.

Comment: You would like arrival rate to be smaller than service rate, but that does not always happen. When arrival rate exceeds service rate, either the queue "explodes" (keeps growing) or customers balk (look at the line and go elsewhere) or renege (get in line, wait a while, get fed up and bail out).